# Debugging java file compiling (using gwt)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I was asked in a precedent question to be more precise about my compilation error message. Here's the fact : I know nothing about GWT and Java. Following the docs, I tried to compile Java files from a web project that had been precedently developed using GWT. So, to test and understand how all this work, I took the java folder (that had been precedently compiled with an appropriate tool)
into src folder of a web app project in my ide Eclipse

When running the compiler using the command GWT Compile, I had this message error :

Compiling module java.org.primagora
Validating newly compiled units
Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
Finding entry point classes
  [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.client.primagoraEntryPoint'
     [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'org.client.primagoraEntryPoint' is really what you meant
     [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots

When I look at the error on the file, for example java.org.client.primagoraEntryPoint, I find an error when it is declared "package org.client" at the very beginning of the file. There seem to be an error path. I thought the java folder I took would be correctly implemented in Eclipse.

Is that clearly a file path problem ? How should I debugg it ? (I reallly know nothing about gwt, java , eclipse)

Best, 
Newben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your GWT module file (i.e. a file that ends in `.gwt.xml`), and what are its contents? The package you list for your entrypoint is `org.client`, and the full name is `org.client.primagoraEntryPoint`, suggesting that there is a file in `org/client/primagoraEntryPoint.java`. By default, module files include the `client` package relative to them as source, so if the file is in the wrong location, this won't work correctly.

Based on this, your module file should be in the `org` package:

```
src/
    org/
        SampleModule.gwt.xml
        client/
            primagoraEntryPoint.java
```

From the very beginning of your error, you list `java.org.primagora` as the module:

> Compiling module java.org.primagora

This suggests the following structure:

```
src/
    org/
        client/
            primagoraEntryPoint.java
    java/
        org/
            primagora.gwt.xml
```

This doesn't make sense, since GWT is now looking for a `java.org.client` package instead of a `org.client` package. Try using the package setup mentioned earlier here.

A better option might be to pick an existing working project, like what the GWT plugin for Eclipse will create, or one of the samples in the GWT download.